# How to read a ArrayList<T> object from JMS queue?

Tags: java, arraylist, jms

I'm new to java and I'm trying to read & write a collection object `ArrayList<T>` into a JMS queue. I'm able to write the object into the queue using the following snippet.

```
List<Request> reqList = new ArrayList<Request>();
... code that populates the list ...
ObjectMessage om = session.createObjectMessage((Serializable) requestList);
```

The above code part is working fine and I can see the records in the `JMS` queue. Now I'm not able to read back the records from the queue and below is the code snippet.

```
@Override
public void onMessage(Message msg)
{
    try {
        String msgText;
        msgText = msg.toString();
        List<Request> requestList = null;
        requestList = msg.getBody(ArrayList<Request>);

    } catch (JMSException jmse) {
        System.err.println("An exception occurred: " + jmse.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I couldn't finish the method because I'm getting an error at line 4. The method getBody expects the type of class where I'm failing to provide. I tried with different options like `Request[].class`, `ArrayList.class`, and `request.getClass()`.

But none of them seems working. Could anyone help me in specifying the right type for `ArrayList<T>` or `List<T>` and how to get it?

Just for information, the method declaration of getBody in `javax.jms` api is

```
public <T extends Object> T getBody(Class<T> type) throws JMSException;
```

I appreciate your help.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to send it like this;

```
ArrayList<Request> reqList = new ArrayList<Request>();
ObjectMessage objectMessage = session.createObjectMessage();
objectMessage.setObject(reqList);
producer.send(objectMessage);
```

and read it like this:

```
...
if (message instanceof ObjectMessage) {
Object object = ((ObjectMessage) message).getObject();
ArrayList<Request> request = (ArrayList<Request>) object);
...
```

If that doesn't work, try creating and object that holds multiple options like Requests that has as a field a List of Request. Dont't forget that Requests object must implement Seriazable.

Answer (score 0):

In the statement `msg.getBody(ArrayList<Request>)`, replace `ArrayList<Request>` with `List.class`.

The method is expecting a `Class` reference, rather than simply the name of the class. Without the `.class` suffix, `ArrayList` is just the type name, rather than a class reference. This will still generate a raw type warning, which (unfortunately) you'll have to suppress with `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")`.

There are a few alternatives to avoid the raw types error if you find suppressing the warning distasteful or ineffective. You can use `Serializable.class` as the body return type, and then cast that to `List<Request>`. That avoids the raw types warning, but will cause an unchecked cast warning instead. Again, this can be silenced with an `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` applied directly to the local variable where the assignment is being done (i.e. not at the method level). There's no real way around this one without suppressing the warning.